# Vite does not build tailwind based on config

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss, vite

I created a new `react-ts` app using `yarn create @vitejs/app my-app --template react-ts`.

I installed tailwind using `yarn add --dev tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`.

I initialized tailwind: `npx tailwindcss init -p`.

I set `from` and `to` in `postcss.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  from: 'src/styles/App.css',
  to: 'src/styles/output.css',
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {}
  }
}
```

I created a `App.css` file in `src/styles`:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

According to https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#postcss, any valid `postcss-load-config` syntax is allowed. `from` and `to` [seem to be allowed](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-load-config#to).

When I call `yarn dev` which essentially runs `vite`, my app is starting without build errors but tailwind output is not generated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it sounds like the package.json tailwind dev dependency needs to be installed by running yarn (or npm install)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`from` and `to` are not required.

I had to update my `import` statement for the css file in `main.tsx` to point to `src/styles/App.css` which will cause `vite` to run `postcss`.

Comment: Could you elaborate giving some code example, I couldn't picture how you did, please.

Answer (score 12):

make sure your postcss.config.js file is in your app root directory

Answer (score 11):

In your vite.config.js, make sure to include Tailwind in your plugins.

```
plugins: [react(),tailwindcss()],
```

Also, you can import Tailwind with the following.

```
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss';
```

Comment: I get this Typescript error: `Type 'Plugin | Processor' is not assignable to type 'PluginOption'. Type 'Plugin' is not assignable to type 'PluginOption'.` - postcss v8.4.21, tailwindcss v3.2.7, vite v4.1.0

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to include in the file tailwind.config.js in the content array the file extension used in your tool.

I used VueJs since it has .vue file extension you need to add it to the content.

Ex.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,vue}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: The 'vue' part was missing in my tailwind.config.js, as it isn't mentioned in the official tailwind documentation. Adding that fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

it solved my problem

> tailwind.config.js

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    // classes that are generated dynamically, e.g. `rounded-${size}` and must
    // be kept
    safeList: [],
    content: [
      './index.html',
      './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts}',
      // etc.
    ],
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: This answer helped me. For future debuggers, make sure the "content" key points to some files :+1:

Answer (score 4):

You have to install postcss autoprefixer if you want to use tailwindcss with vite.

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

if you are using only react
then use

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
```

check the docs
it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS THE ULTIMATE WHOLESOME SOLUTION:**

Follow this link [tailwind installation guideline](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss) to install it your application then:

1. Make sure the following lines files are in your root folder

   - postcss.config.js
   - tailwind.config.js
2. convert the code in the above files into ES6
   **postcss.config.js file contents:**
   `export const plugins = {`
   `tailwindcss: {},`
   `autoprefixer: {}`
   `};`

**tailwindcss.config.js**

`/** @type {import(tailwindcss').Config */`
`export const content = ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,tsx}"];`
`export const theme = {`
`extend: {},`
`};`
`export const plugins = [];`

3. Add the **@tailwind directives** for each of Tailwind’s layers to your main CSS file and make sure it is imported in your entry file.
   `@tailwind base;`
   `@tailwind components;`
   `@tailwind utilities;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are forget to fill content object in tailwind config

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/*.{js,jsx}', './src/**/*.{js,jsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: This is actually the comment that worked for me. If these content strings are missing tailwind wont work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Vite just use:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by importing the `index.css` to my `main.jsx` file:

Import to your `main.jsx` file:

```
import './index.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are following this video like me, you can try instead your `tailwind. config` with this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx}"],
  mode: "jit",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#050816",
        secondary: "#aaa6c3",
        tertiary: "#151030",
        "black-100": "#100d25",
        "black-200": "#090325",
        "white-100": "#f3f3f3",
      },
      boxShadow: {
        card: "0px 35px 120px -15px #211e35",
      },
      screens: {
        xs: "450px",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        "hero-pattern": "url('/src/assets/herobg.png')",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

In my case when i added postcss.config,vite throw an error contains message `[ReferenceError] module is not defined in ES module scope` so  i removed   `"type": "module"` in package.json then it's started to work

Update:- when i followed installation steps from  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite `"type": "module"` has not thrown any error

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Create postcss.config.cjs file not js rememeber that change js with cjs after it add this in your postcss.config.cjs

```
 module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
      // Add other PostCSS plugins here if needed
    },
  }
```

and now add this in your vite.config.js file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import WindiCSS from 'vite-plugin-windicss'; // Import WindiCSS plugin

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    WindiCSS(), 
  ],
});
```

Now your good to go it's best solution

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `postcss.config.cjs` in root directory

File content:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```